# Multiple conditions for a cell value in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm an insurance broker and currently I'm using Microsoft Excel to organize my insurance commissions. There are multiple insurance companies I'm cooperating with, like `{Asia, Iran, Dey}` and each of them offers a variety of insurance policies which I have selected a few to simplify the question: `{Liability, Life, Third Party, Health}`. Each company calculates commissions differently, as an example `Dey` would calculate commissions related to `Liability` policies with `30 Percents`.

What I want to do is an excel document which the first column is the `Premium` which I **type in** for every policy; Imagine `$200` for a `Life` insurance sold by `Asia`. The second column will be the insurance companies name - selected from a **dropdown list** -, in this case `Asia`. Next Column should be another **dropdown list** with policies that in this example I should choose `life`. at this point I want an automated process which understands that this was a `life insurance policy` by `Asia`, so the commission should be calculated with 8 percents and print this into the next column. and automatically multiply the premium and commission percentage `($200 * 8% = $16)` and output this number to the last column.

I have prepared a schematic image of what information I have :
[Schematic design of my information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45ran.png)

I used to do this with extremely nested `if` and `and` with 2 insurance companies but when the third one was added I ran out of options.

Comment: You need two **dependent dropdowns** and two lookup tables.

Comment: @Jeeped I have two dependent dropdowns but can you please explain lookup tables? I have no information about what it is or how it works and how it would help me.

Comment: I am guessing the lookup tables will be tables holding info that you want to lookup e.g. percentage to apply by company, where you have a list of companies in one column and the percentage  to apply in the adjacent column, and you use the company name (perhaps from drop down?) to then lookup the relevant percentage in the table.  But that is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, the lookup table (G1:I13) retrieves the commission percentage. This is used to calculate the actual commission from the policy cost.

```
=INDEX(I:I, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$99)/(($G$2:$G$99=$B2)*($H$2:$H$9=$C2)), 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain it a little? I looked up index and aggregate functions in Microsoft website and read the documents but couldn't understand what u did there. Since I need to implement this in my existing file and change it a little, I have to have a little understanding of what it does. Also Is it possible for the tables to be in another sheet?